# Crash at android.inputmethodservice.IInputMethodWrapper.setSessionEnabled(IInputMethodWrapper.java:280)

Tags: android, error-handling, runtimeexception, android-input-method

My app crashes on Android 4 devices. It happens when I`m scrolling recyclerView in the viewPager
why this error may occur?

```
 0805/? W/Binder: Caught a RuntimeException from the binder stub implementation.
                                             java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                 at android.inputmethodservice.IInputMethodWrapper.setSessionEnabled(IInputMethodWrapper.java:280)
                                                 at com.android.internal.view.IInputMethod$Stub.onTransact(IInputMethod.java:129)
                                                 at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
    08-16 10:58:44.238 926-10805/? W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException
    08-16 10:58:44.244 926-10805/? W/System.err:     at android.inputmethodservice.IInputMethodWrapper.setSessionEnabled(IInputMethodWrapper.java:280)
    08-16 10:58:44.245 926-10805/? W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.view.IInputMethod$Stub.onTransact(IInputMethod.java:129)
    08-16 10:58:44.245 926-10805/? W/System.err:     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
    08-16 10:58:44.245 926-10805/? W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

Comment: Are you having any service in you app?

Comment: Same issue here, anyone? Happens to me restarting app - have some services but I stop them before.

Comment: Any Solution guys ? having this problem in Android 4.4

Answer (score 0):

Maybe U implementation some libraries in your **module** gradle is lower. Just like

```
implementation 'com.android.support:leanback-v17:25.3.1'
```

try change to

```
implementation 'com.android.support:leanback-v17:26.1.0'
```